# C# - run two task parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await

I want to run two task parallel, the goal is: while there is countdown, I want to have locked input. When the counter will be 0, then program should stop locking input. So far, I know how to block input for a while, but at the same time I want to have timer which will tell me how long it will takes. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();

            while (timeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                program.timer();
                //Program.BlockInput(timeSpan);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private void timer()
        {
            timeSpan -= new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ToString());
        }

        private partial class NativeMethods
        {
            [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "BlockInput")]
            [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);
        }

        private static void BlockInput(TimeSpan span)
        {
            try
            {
                NativeMethods.BlockInput(true);
                Thread.Sleep(span);
            }
            finally
            {
                NativeMethods.BlockInput(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You talk about 2 parallel tasks ? I don't see any in your code. "I want to have timer which will tell me how long it will takes" : the execution time of your tasks ? Or the delay of the BlockInput ?

Comment: Ok, I want to have blocked input for some period. And while the input will be blocked I want to see on console the time which is counting to zero.

Comment: There seams to be an upsurge in people trying to write malware as of late strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simply another thread.
Your counter is counting and input is blocked, while you can do anything else because these actions are on another thread.

```
public void RunTwoThingsAtOnce()
{
    new Thread( () =>
    {
        while (timeSpan > TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            program.timer();
            //Input Block
        }

     }).Start();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Better than threads is to use async/await. The following task will be run on the thread pool. You don't need a dedicated thread for this problem.

```
    private static async Task BlockInput(TimeSpan span)
    {
        return Task.Run(()=>{
            try
            {
                NativeMethods.BlockInput(true);
                await Task.Delay(span);
            }
            finally
            {
                NativeMethods.BlockInput(false);
            }

        });


    }
```